# Приведение несовместимых типов Java, механизм

Tags: java, типы-данных

Не могу понять, что именно происходит при приведении типов. С плавающей точкой все просто, отбрасывается дробная часть. Но как осуществляется приведение, например, к типу byte?

```
public class Cast {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte b;

        int i=128;

        b = (byte) i;

        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Если `i = 128`, `b = -128`; если `i = 257`, `b = 1`. Как это высчитывается?

Comment: предположу, что берутся нижние 8 битов, все остальное отрезается. в этом случае бит, который отличает 128 от нуля встанет на место sign bit, и число будет воспринято как отрицательное, в случае с 257 старший бит отрежется и останется только 00000001.

Comment: Точно, так и есть, благодарю!

Comment: а зачем производить подобные преобразования?

Comment: Ну, я на данном этапе изучения языка просто стараюсь охватить все возможности Java, а если не понимаю механизм, то и усвоить, соответственно, не могу, отсюда и вопрос появился.

Comment: А тут, собственно, от java и нет ничего. Если у вас число занимает 4 байта, а вы ходите его запихнуть в 1 байт, то единственное решение - это отбросить 3 байта.